# Magnitude of Strain Tensor

Tags: elasticity, continuum-mechanics

What is the physical interpretation of "magnitude" of the Strain tensor? For the strain tensor $e_{ik}$ its magnitude is defined by:

$$
e_{ik}e_{ik}=e_{11}^2 + e_{22}^2+e_{33}^2 + 2e_{12}^2+ 2e_{13}^2+ 2e_{23}^2
$$

Comment: There is an infinity of possibilities to define a strain tensor. They are all based on the deformation gradient and usually belong to the Seth-Hill family.

Which strain are you referring to in particular?